# Can I install my own Minecraft skin in Xbox 360?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have just made my own Minecraft skin that I will be using for my PC version for Minecraft. Is it also possible I could transfer this somehow to my Xbox 360? Possibly with a flash drive or potentially something else?

Comment: Can you upload it to the Skindex?

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot. Unless you hack the skin into your xbox's game somehow, you can only use skins included in skin packs.